# Formatting the output stream, ios::left and ios::right

Tags: c++, stream, iostream

I have this code:

```
cout << std::setiosflags(std::ios::right);
cout << setw(3) << 1 << setw(3) << 2 << '\n'; // Output two values

cout << std::setiosflags(std::ios::left);
cout << setw(3) << 1 << setw(3) << 2 << '\n'; // Output two values
```

but the output doesnt come like i expected. instead of:

```
  1  2
1  2
```

this comes out:

```
  1  2
  1  2
```

What is the problem? I set 'std::ios::left' but it makes no difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to clear the previous value in adjustfield before you can set a new one.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main () {
  std::cout << std::resetiosflags(std::ios::adjustfield);
  std::cout << std::setiosflags(std::ios::right);
  std::cout << std::setw(3) << 1 << std::setw(3) << 2 << '\n';

  std::cout << std::resetiosflags(std::ios::adjustfield);
  std::cout << std::setiosflags(std::ios::left);
  std::cout << std::setw(3) << 1 << std::setw(3) << 2 << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Unless you're feeling masochistic, just use:

```
// right justify by default.
cout << setw(3) << 1 << setw(3) << 2 << '\n';

// left justify
cout << std::left << setw(3) << 1 << setw(3) << 2 << '\n';

// right justify again.
cout << std::right << setw(3) << 1 << setw(3) << 2 << '\n';
```

Answer (score 8):

Use setf with a mask (no need for resetiosflags)

```
using namespace std;
cout.setf(ios::right, ios::adjustfield);
cout << setw(3) << 1 << setw(3) << 2 << '\n'; // Output two values

cout.setf(ios::left, ios::adjustfield);
cout << setw(3) << 1 << setw(3) << 2 << '\n'; // Output two values
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code wants a `std::resetiosflags(std::ios::right)` sent to the output stream to undo the preceding `std::setiosflags(std::ios::right)`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like if both `left` and `right` flags are set, the one that was set first takes precedence. If I explicitly reset `right` flag before setting `left`, I get the output you expected:

```
cout << std::setiosflags(std::ios::right);
cout << setw(3) << 1 << setw(3) << 2 << '\n'; // Output two values

cout << resetiosflags(std::ios::right);

cout << std::setiosflags(std::ios::left);
cout << setw(3) << 1 << setw(3) << 2 << '\n'; // Output two values
```