# C++ setiosflags function manipulator - undetermined indentation

Tags: c++, indentation, cout, manipulators

I am studying C++ and I am focusing on `cout` manipulator functions.

By running the following code I get an indentation in the second line containing `Gauthier`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << std::setiosflags(std::ios::left)
        << "Mathieu\n"
        << "Gauthier\n"
        << "Paul\n"
        << "Louis\n"
        << "Pierre\n"
        << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain to me what is happening?
Why `Gauthier` is indented while the other names are not?

```
Mathieu
  Gauthier
Paul
Louis
Pierre

Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which iomanip manipulators are 'sticky'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532640/which-iomanip-manipulators-are-sticky)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::ios::left` tells to add fill characters to the right, i.e. it adds few characters to first string, so `"Mathieu\n"` "becomes" `"Mathieu\n  "`. There is new line character at the end (`'\n'`), so added spaces are moved to next line (`Gauthier`). So it's not indentation of second line, those are trailing characters from first.

Comment: This is a surprising answer (and it doesn't sound that bad). However, I made this [**Test fiddling on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0f6738a53b178ea) which I struggle to fit into your explanation.

Comment: If this is true, why do spaces not get added to the other, even shorter, names? (Hint: we think `setw()` is the real key here)

Comment: `std::cout <<std::setiosflags(std::ios::left) << 43 ;` but the output does not match your explaination.

Comment: Even more funny: Resetting with `std::setw(0)` at begin of each output line doesn't change the result: [**Further test fiddling on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f1dd4fb0f7506d5)

Comment: @Scheff The answer explains your code. The only missing part of the answer is that `setw` is not sticky.

Comment: OK. Concerning the strange effects in my fiddling, I found the answer in [SO: Formatting the output stream, ios::left and ios::right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9947528/7478597). Fixing this, I get [**Fixed test fiddling on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27ce882cd3f8b1d7), and, now, your explanation makes perfectly sense (to me). Though, the `std::resetiosflags(std::ios::adjustfield)` is something I find worth mentioned in your answer as well... ;-)

Comment: @cygien Did you notice that the `std::ios::left` resulted in distinct effects in my first and second test? ;-) Though, I found the explanation for this as well.